# getting error when using () on function call

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with `nicEdit`, a `WYSIWYG` editor (http://nicedit.com/)

It is quite straightforward to use. Need to add just the following two lines to code

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

My `html` is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- add list of tags here in meta data -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    <title>some title</title>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea id="d" type="text"></textarea>
    <textarea id="s" type="text"></textarea>
    <textarea id="h" type="text"></textarea>

    <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas)</script>
    <-- ISSUE HERE IF I USE () -->
</body>

</html>
```

It seems I can pass configuration options to the editor - http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options

I want to call the `allTextAreas` by passing a configuration object to it. But when I call the `allTextAreas` by adding `({someProperty:someValue})`, I get error in the console

```
nicEdit-latest.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: bkLib.domLoad[i] is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.domLoaded (nicEdit-latest.js:8)
domLoaded @ nicEdit-latest.js:8
```

Why does using `()` give error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks it needs a function, try wrap it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(() => nicEditors.allTextAreas({someProperty: someValue}))</script>
```

---

#### Explain

`bkLib.onDomLoaded` accepts a callback function.

- `nicEditors.allTextAreas` works because it's a function, but you will not be able to pass custom argument when it's get called.
- `() => nicEditors.allTextAreas({someProperty: someValue})` works because it wraps `nicEditors.allTextAreas` in another function, and when it's get called, the `{someProperty: someValue}` is passed into it.
- `nicEditors.allTextAreas({someProperty: someValue})` doesn't work because it calls that function immediately and resolves whatever it returns and passed it into `bkLib.onDomLoaded`. Which I assume is not what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. It did work. Could you also please explain why it did? Is it that calling `allTextAreas` passes a function but `allTextAreas()` passes result of its execution and thus the code didn't work?

Comment: @ManuChadha I updated the answer and tried to explain. Please excuse my English :p